# Able to create tables dynamically and also filter data dynamically using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a stored procedure that retrieves billions of records and there is requirement to store the result set into a table. Since it is in billions and to improve efficiency of client application fetching data,we have come up with an idea of filtering the records based on year and creating a table dynamically and inserting the resultset into that table. The business is interested in only pulling last five years. This will drastically reduce the amount of data as well improve the performance of the front end application querying smaller tables.

I am currently using SSIS 2016 to do it. Could somebody tell me if there is a way of achieving this in SSIS ?

Comment: Billions of records... sounds like a case for the Microsoft APS / PDW... However: did you consider partitioning your table instead of splitting it up into numerous tables? Should provide a pretty efficient way to extract certain years only..

Comment: How do I achieve partitioning table ? Any ideas

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2888/how-to-partition-an-existing-sql-server-table/

Comment: My problem is different. Partitioning existing table  might help for my front end application but not for data migration. I need it to be dynamic. So these tables need to be created when the migration runs. So say the current year is 2017 and we need last five years, it should be able to create tables table_2013, table_2014,table_2015,table_2016 and table_2017 and then store the resultset in each of these tables based on the date filter

Comment: Yes, but as far as I am informed you can create a table already partitioned... e.g.  if you partition the table by year and then migrate all data where date >= 01.01.2013 (for your example 2017 - 4 years). However, if you have to split the data into separate tables, this should be possible as well. I would suggest to create a string variable which stores the parametrized query ('....where year = ' + (DT_WSTR, 4)@[User::MyYear]), a string variable which stores the parametrized DDL ('CREATE TABLE table_' + (DT_WSTR, 4)@[User::MyYear]) and an object variable for looping through the years.

Comment: Can you clarify your question- which bit are you wondering whether SSIS can achieve? Creating a table? inserting data? Will the package need to just create one subset or does it need to split it by year and make x tables for x years? Tyron's suggestion is one reasonable way of doing it.

Comment: Tyron could you elaborate a but further if possible with example

Comment: I am looking at how to achieve this in SSIS

Comment: Hi Rich, I am looking at improving the migration speed. Also taking into account that I have all that data in one table , it would slow the front end. I am basically looking at various options. So I am thinking of having multiple physical  tables.  Will it be faster If I  execute 5 different versions of the same stored procedures with different year filters and popuate the tables . I know one can achieve parallelism in SSIS.  My only fear is since all the five storedprocedures are running in parallel , will they lock down the tables.